# Unable to create/access database

Tags: mongodb, go

I have been using MongoDB without issues in Python but I am in need to build a client in go now.
I have looked at the documentation and the examples work fine.
But when I try to use my own code, the code execute without errors, but when I inspect the database (via CLI) I see no database, no collection and no data.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I am unable to find it in this little testing code.

```
func main() {

    if client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")); err == nil {
        ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
        defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
        if err = client.Connect(ctx); err == nil {
            os.Exit(0)
        }

        KeysCol := client.Database("yfroot").Collection("KeysCol")

        mac, e1 := crypto.GenerateRandomBytes(16)
        key, e2 := crypto.GenerateRandomBytes(16)
        if e1 != nil || e2 != nil {
            fmt.Println("failed crypto generate")
            os.Exit(0)
        }
        testKey := dataformats.DeviceKey{
            Mac: string(mac),
            Key: key,
        }

        // ctx, _ = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(10)*time.Second)
        _, err := KeysCol.InsertOne(ctx, testKey)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(0)
        }

    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part:

```
if err = client.Connect(ctx); err == nil {
  os.Exit(0)
}
```

If you are able to connect, that us (`err` is `nil`), you are exiting.

You probably meant to do:

```
if err = client.Connect(ctx); err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  os.Exit(0)
}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid .... time t for a brak instead of wasting time for people here.

Comment: @Francesco It's easy to become blind like that. Been there done that.

Comment: The record still is not stored, must be another typo somewhere. Thanks.